# Remote Virtual Machine stuck in shutdown loop

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows scheduled task set up to run evey minute which restarts the machine.

I cannot remote on as it's stuck in a loop.

How can I resolve this? :(

Comment: Is it a _remote_ machine or your machine? If you have physical access just start in _safe mode_ or in recovery console. Anyway I think on SuperUser you may get more detailed answers.

Comment: Do you have access (file sharing) to that machine (for the few seconds it's on-line?) and do you have administrative rights? If this is the case just `notepad \\remote_computer_name\c$\boot.ini` to add `/safeboot:network` to start in safe mode (check syntax on your local file, see also [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239780)). It should take no more than 5 seconds. Next time it'll restart it'll be in safe mode, you can then remove that task and restore unmodified `boot.ini`.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, good knowledge for me to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to run `shutdown /a` within endless loop using [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from your local PC:

`AbortShutdown.cmd`:

```
:abort
psexec.exe -s \\RemoteVM shutdown /a
goto abort
```

In theory, this should abort shutdown attempts, so you could logon to VM an disable scheduled task.

You could also remotely disable\rename scheduled task, depending of which OS you use: [Is it possible to disable a scheduled task from the command line in Windows XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/164097/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-scheduled-task-from-the-command-line-in-windows-xp)

To disable scheduled task in XP\2003:

```
psexec.exe -s \\RemoteVM move "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\Shutdown.job" "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\Shutdown.bak"
```

To disable scheduled task in Vista\2008:

```
psexec.exe -s \\RemoteVM schtasks.exe /Change /TN "Shutdown" /Disable
```

Answer (score -1):

Press F8 depending on the OS when it reboots and it would go into safe mode where you can turn off the schedule task.